# return no longLived CKOperation

Tags: ckcontainer, ckoperation

1. I created a CKOperation whose longLived was set "true".
2. Turn on flight mode for my iPhone(iOS 9.3.5)
3. kill app
4. relaunch, and found no longLived operations

   ```
   [[CKContainer defaultContainer] fetchAllLongLivedOperationIDsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray<NSString *> * _Nullable outstandingOperationIDs, NSError * _Nullable error) {
   if (error) {
       NSLog(@"----------error---  %@", error);
   }else {
       NSLog(@"outstandingOperationIDs: %@", outstandingOperationIDs);  **// always return ()**
   }
   }];
   ```

Comment: Hi, did you ever get this resolved? I'm stuck with a similar issue.

Comment: I can't find enough resources, so I dropped this solution. I'm sorry.